# Number of steps to transform X to Y. (Integers)

Tags: c, algorithm, recursion

So I am confused on how this recursive function works. I don't understand how this actually produces the answer. The question states:

Write a recursive function that returns the minimum number of steps
necessary to transform X to Y. If X > Y, return 1000000000, to indicate that no solution exists.(For example, if X = 13 and Y = 28, the correct response would be 2 - first you would add 1 to13 to obtain 14, then multiply 14 by 2 to obtain 28.) Feel free to call the provided function

This is the solution:

```
int min(int x, int y) {
    if (x < y) return x;
    return y;
}

// Returns the minimum number of steps to transform x into y, or
// 100000000 to indicate no solution.
int minSteps(int x, int y) {
    if (x > y) return NO_SOLUTION; 
    if (x == y) return 0; 
    int mult = 1 + minSteps(2*x, y);
    int add = 1 + minSteps(x+1, y); 
    return min(add, mult); 
}
```

If someone can please explain the solution that will be great. Thanks!

Comment: Every integer can be represented as a sum of integer powers of two.

Comment: Minumum number of steps for `x->y` is one plus the minimum between either `2*x->y` or `x+1->y`. Do you agree?

Comment: MSVC's `stdlib.h` already has the macros `min` and `max`.

Comment: Also, if you calculate `minSteps(1073741824, 2073741824)`, is the result of `1000000000` a solution or an indication that there is no solution?

Comment: Actually, I think minSteps(1073741824, 2073741824) result of 1000000000 will work fine.  The question is what happens with minSteps(1073741824, 2073741825) which should result in 1000000001?  Will it return 1000000000 instead?

Comment: Note if `2*x` overflows, code is likely lost. Add a `if (x > INT_MAX/2) return 1000000000;` prior to that call.  Negative numbers are another story.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the core of many problems that can be solved with recursion lies the principle of reduction of the original problem to a smaller one and continuing the process until it diminishes to a known one.

This problem perfectly suits for such approach.
Your answer is a series of arithmetic operations that convert `x` to `y`. I.e., something like this:

> x ? a ? b ? c ? ... ? y

Where `?` denotes either multiplication by `2` or addition of `1`; and `a`,`b`,`c`... represent the intermediate results after applying the operation on a previous result. For example, transformation of `5` to `22` can be described this way:

> 5 (*2) 10 (+1) 11 (*2) 22

Now let's get back to the reduction principle. Starting with a given x, we need to choose the first step. It can be either `*2` **OR**<sup>[1]</sup> `+1`, we don't know it yet, so we need to check them both. In the case of `*2`, the `x` transforms to `2x` and in the case of `+1`, the `x` transforms to `x+1`. And voila, we progressed one step and reduced the problem! Now we have 2 smaller problems to solve - one for `2x` and one for `x+1`, and find the minimum between the results. Since we're counting the steps, we create `2` distinct counters (one for each type of operation taken) and add `1` to each one of them (since we performed one step already). To complete the calculation of the actual value of each counter we need to solve the two smaller problems - and to solve them we call the function recursively with the new input (twice, once per input). The algorithm continues this way, reducing the problem each time until getting to a stop condition, which can be either `x == y` (it's a valid transformation) or `x > y` (invalid transformation). In case of `x == y` there are exactly `0` steps required and the execution stops, causing the call stack to fall back, populating the actual value of the counter that originated the recursion branch. In case of `x > y` the result is `1000000000` (which is assumed to be too large to be an actual result and thus the sum will be dropped as larger than the sum from the second branch). This process is usually better understood by visualizing with recursion tree (see @DavidBowling answer, for example. Err, deleted for some reason...).

<sup>[1]</sup> Although in this problem it's very clear, but sometimes the distinction between the operations can be vague. It's very important to dissect the problem into a number of smaller ones, **without any overlap** between them.

Comment: Nice explanation of recursion as a reduction principle.  A very good general explanation of the process.  I'd still like to understand for myself better exactly how the algorithm is effectively dealing with cases like minSteps(3,28) and minSteps(2,28).  Not sure why DavidBowling's answer was deleted.  I also thought it made some good points.

Comment: There is nothing special in these cases. When the stack reaches the stop condition and begins to fold back, the result is building up by summing minimums of the underlying calculations. I suggest to just draw a recursion tree of a small example problem, it should become clear.

Comment: I agree there is nothing special.  I think the answer to my own question is this: the process is always binary.  At each step the problem is broken into both x*2 and x+1 for that step, and so on for each next step as you note:  The key is that in this way the algorithm actually tests EVERY POSSIBLE PATH (every possible combination of x+1s and x*2s) and takes the minimum of all.  It was not obvious to me at first that it was trying every path.  Of course it abandons any path that exceeds Y as soon as it exceeds Y.

Comment: Perfect explanation. Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

This is actually a nice example to help teach recursion.  Not sure if I can explain it, but will take a shot.  To be clear, there are only two kinds of steps: either doubling X, or adding 1 to X.

The best way to understand this is to follow an example through the code.

I've deleted the rest of my answer for now.  Playing with this in a debugger.  It's actually quite elegant but I don't feel I can yet explain exactly how its working before playing with it some more.

Still not up to explaining it, but take a look at this:

```
minSteps(16, 28) = 12
minSteps(15, 28) = 13
minSteps(14, 28) =  1
minSteps(13, 28) =  2
minSteps(12, 28) =  3
minSteps(11, 28) =  4
minSteps(10, 28) =  5
minSteps( 9, 28) =  6
minSteps( 8, 28) =  7
minSteps( 7, 28) =  2
minSteps( 6, 28) =  3
minSteps( 5, 28) =  4
minSteps( 4, 28) =  5
minSteps( 3, 28) =  4
minSteps( 2, 28) =  5
minSteps( 1, 28) =  6
```

Notice in particular:

```
minSteps( 5, 28) =  4 // x+1 twice  (5->7), then x*2 twice (7->14->28)
minSteps( 4, 28) =  5 // x+1 thrice (4->7), then x*2 twice (7->14->28)
minSteps( 3, 28) =  4 // x*2 (3->6), then x+1 (6->7), then x*2 twice (7->14->28)
minSteps( 2, 28) =  5 // x+1 (2->3), then x*2 (3->6), then x+1 (6->7), then x*2 twice (7->14->28)
```

To me, it seems relatively easy to see how the algorithm can get correct any case of just multiplying by 2 repeatedly, or any case of first adding 1 some number of times and then multiplying by 2 repeatedly.  That is correctly the minimum number of steps in almost every case above.

But the cases of minSteps(3,28) and minSteps(2,28) are really quite interesting, because the minimum number of steps for those cases involves switching back and forth between x*2 and x+1.  And yet the algorithm gets it right.

There is actually nothing special about these cases. The answer is this: The process is always binary. At each step the problem is broken into both x*2 and x+1 for that step, and so on for each next step as you note: **The key is that in this way the algorithm actually tests EVERY POSSIBLE PATH (every possible combination of x+1s and x*2s)** *and takes the minimum of all possible paths.* It was not obvious to me at first that it was trying every path. Of course it abandons any path that exceeds Y as soon as it exceeds Y.

Comment: You'll have to explain the claim about the order of adding and multiplying some more. From where I'm standing, both of these are pure functions and the order that they are called in doesn't matter in the least.

Comment: You have a fundamental error in the description. It doesn't matter whether doubling or addition is first. It's a choice of a **single, current step only**. After that the problem reduces to a smaller one with a new choice consisting of both doubling and addition. The algorithm doesn't find the "maximum number of times that you can multiply". Consider getting from 1 to 127. You'll multiply by 2 till 64 and add 1 63 times after that. That wouldn't be the correct answer.

Comment: Yes ... Looked through the code again.  You are correct, order does not matter.  My bad.  Will edit that out of the answer.